# Is the Aggregator Pattern with Multiple Clients in Microservice Architecture Valid?

Tags: microservices, architectural-patterns

Say two microservices provide information for a product, one is providing general information (A), one for product images (B). Similar to the architecture described in [the gateway aggregation pattern](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/gateway-aggregation), I would like to create an aggregation gateway between these services A & B.

Now if multiple applications would access that aggregation gateway as in below image, would that be in conflict with microservice architecture?

[image: Multi-Client Aggregator Gateway]

Comment: What do you mean by "valid" and "in conflict?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we see this pattern a lot in a mini format, the "backend for frontend" kind of thing. But I *do* think is is a bit of an anti pattern.

The problem as I see it is that the Aggregator can become super thin. Adding no extra functionality that couldn't be directly implemented on the Application, or indeed the Front End.

But you can't remove the extra constraints that the Aggregate adds, extra boxes, networking, an extra bottleneck, extra code.

In your example, for example, one of the benefits of the micro-service approach might be that if you can't get images, you can still get product listings, the application doesn't completely break if one part breaks.

Or that, if we found images were slow, we could horizontally scale the image service.

Although he Aggregator doesn't make these things impossible, and there is a fuzzy transition from 'Service which has its own logic/data but depends on other microservices' to 'Gateway which simply passes messages on'. My feeling is that you are working against the flow introducing elements between a MicroService and its consumers.

Comment: I definitely see the point. My problem in this case is that Service A in above case has a bit of a messy API which requires applications to chain multiple requests. Service A and B have a lot of consuming Applications where code sharing becomes an issue because every application has to re-do the integration. So I guess I need to decide between the code sharing anti pattern and this one.

Comment: improve As Api? add a wrapper for A alone?

Comment: publish a client for A which makes it easier to use?

Comment: I'm guessing improving the API would be the best option but there are business side limitations that make them infeasible for my team so we have to go with one of the others. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think there is anything wrong with hierarchical services as long as they don’t form circular dependencies or other nasty anti-patterns.

I would just analyze whether it’s more convenient for me to have it in every client and save server  CPU or have it on the server and simplify upgrading and testing.